# How can I manage languages in URI like apache did?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to migrate a website from apache to nginx. In apache, I have the following configuration for managing languages :

```
RewriteRule fr/(.*) /$1?lang=fr [L,QSA]
RewriteRule en/(.*) /$1?lang=en [L,QSA]
```

My root path is `/var/www`.

What I expected :

- static files (js, images, css, etc) should be served as is (ex.: `/css/common.css` should serve `/var/www/css/common.css`)
- `/` is redirected to `/en/`
- `/myscript.php` is redirected to `/en/myscript.php`
- when uri matches with `/(en|fr)/myscript.php` nginx should serve `/var/www/myscript.php` with query `?lang=(en|fr)`
- when uri matches with `/(en|fr)/myscript.php?foo=bar` nginx should serve `/var/www/myscript.php` with query `?lang=(en|fr)&foo=bar`

Here is my actual nginx configuration :

```
root /var/www;
index index.php;
                                     
error_page 404 /error404.php;

location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

How can I manage this with `try_files` and `rewrite` ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to rewrite any URI that begins with `/en` or `/fr`. The `rewrite` at `server` scope will be tested before a `location` is selected to process the request, so the simplest solution would be:

```
server {
    ...

    rewrite ^/(en|fr)(/.*)$ $2?lang=$1 last;

    location / { ... }
    location ~ \.php$ { ... }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.